# VBA isnull function

Tags: vba, isnull

[image]
In VBA , is there any function that work in the way similar to  `isnull` in SQL?

E.G.
`A1` is  blank cell,
`B1 = Apple`,
`C1 = Orange`.

For example:

i) `D1 = isnull (A1,B1)`
Target result: `D1 = Apple`

ii)`D1= isnull (B1,C1)`
Target result: `D1 = Apple`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in VBA you can use `IsEmpty()` function:

```
Range("D1").Value = IIf(IsEmpty(Range("A1")), Range("B1").Value, Range("A1").Value)
```

so you can build a UDF like

```
Function MyIsNull(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Variant
    MyIsNull = IIf(IsEmpty(rng1), rng2.Value, rng1.Value)
End Function
```

and call it in your cells like:

i)  `=MyIsNull(A1,B1)`

ii) `=MyIsNull(B1,C1)`

note: I used "MyIsNull" as UDF name because `IsNull` is the name of an already existent VBA function, and should you name your UDF after "IsNull" then it'd hide it

---

While if you want to use excel built in functions you may use `ISBLANK()` and type in your cells:

i)    `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)`
ii)   `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),C1,B1)`

Comment: @ThompsonHo, any feedback?

Comment: Sub test()

      Range("D1").Value = MyIsNull(A1, B1)
  
    End Sub

      Function MyIsNull(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Variant
      MyIsNull = IIf(IsEmpty(rng1), rng2.Value, rng1.Value)
      End Function

Comment: Encounter Error : ByRef argument type mismatch    Do you have idea?

Comment: Thanks but look like the function give me different thing .  Sub test1 using function return "orange" which is wrong, while sub test2 return me "apple", which is correct.       Sub test1() Range("D1").Value = MyIsNull(Range("B1"), Range("C1")
End Sub


Sub test2()
Range("D1").Value = IIf(IsEmpty(Range("B1")), Range("C1").Value, Range("B1").Value)
End Sub

Comment: test1() is missing a closing parenthesys after ‘Range("C1")’.  And I don’t see neither your actual MyIsNull() function nor sheet data